# Laying out buttons and wall of text vertically

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to layout two linear layouts vertically and the first one has sometimes a wall of text and sometimes very short one. While the second linear layout, has two buttons stacked up vertically also.

How do I get the second linear layout with buttons to stay at the bottom of the screen if the text is short or at the end of the paragraph if it is long?

edit: sorry, for not placing the xml right away. it's like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_pdtwo_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            android:text="@string/text_pd_two_intro_title"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_pd_two_headshot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img_pd_two_sample" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_pd_two_review_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.3"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.."
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_pd_two_take_photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="@string/button_pd_two_take_photo"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_pd_two_select_gallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            android:text="@string/button_pd_two_select_gallery"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_pd_two_submit_photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            android:text="@string/button_pd_two_submit_photo"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_pd_two_cancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            android:text="@string/button_pd_two_cancel"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It looks like this when the text is very short, which is good

[image: It looks like this]

But when the text is very long, it gets like this.. I want it to go at the end of the text and perhaps scroll it down before the user actually clicks the button..

[image]

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Please post your XML layout. Thanks.

Comment: apologies, post updated with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work, if there is a better solution please let me know.

For the java file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Integer count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    final Integer vwheight = metrics.heightPixels;

    final LinearLayout top_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.top_layout);
    final LinearLayout bottom_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottom_layout);

    ViewTreeObserver vto = top_layout.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            if (count == 0) {
                int top_layoutMeasuredHeight = top_layout.getMeasuredHeight();

                if (top_layoutMeasuredHeight > vwheight) {

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.top_layout);

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                        relativeParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                    }

                    bottom_layout.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

and for the XML

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/top_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_pdtwo_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/text_pd_two_intro_title"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="23sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_pd_two_headshot"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/img_pd_two_sample" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_pd_two_review_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.3"
                    android:text="@string/text_pd_two_review_content"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_pd_two_take_photo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                    android:text="button_pd_two_take_photo"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_pd_two_select_gallery"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                    android:text="button_pd_two_select_gallery"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_pd_two_submit_photo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                    android:text="button_pd_two_submit_photo"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_pd_two_cancel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                    android:text="button_pd_two_cancel"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Finished product when the text is very long

[image]

and if there is a short text, it stays at the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to add ScrollView in your layout that You can use in this way, by this no one view(TextView or Button) will be overlap to other :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_layout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_pdtwo_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            android:text="@string/text_pd_two_intro_title"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_pd_two_headshot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_pd_two_review_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.3"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.."
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_pd_two_take_photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="button_pd_two_take_photo"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_pd_two_select_gallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            android:text="button_pd_two_select_gallery"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_pd_two_submit_photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            android:text="button_pd_two_submit_photo"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_pd_two_cancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            android:text="button_pd_two_cancel"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

if your text will increase that we need to add scroll in text by this code :

```
/*For scrolling TextView*/
        text_pd_two_review_content.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        text_pd_two_review_content.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i was able to make it work they way I want to and posted an answer but I know for sure it may not be the best approach. If you have a better answer, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Added layout_bove.
Try thins method:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_pdtwo_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
        android:text="@string/text_pd_two_intro_title"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="23sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_pd_two_headshot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_pd_two_sample" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_pd_two_review_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.3"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.."
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />


</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_pd_two_take_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="@string/button_pd_two_take_photo"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_pd_two_select_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_pd_two_select_gallery"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_pd_two_submit_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_pd_two_submit_photo"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_pd_two_cancel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_pd_two_cancel"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use my solution bro

Comment: sir i think you didn't modified any or you pasted the wrong code

Comment: watch android:layout_above="@+id/button_layout" in first linearLayout and in second linearLayout android:id="@+id/button_layout"

Comment: thank you for this,it gave me an idea. i was able to make it work and posted my code above but maybe you have a better answer.